Space are removed for subqueries for GetText() when parsed by ANTL4
I'm using ANTL in my go program.
I have a query
INSERT INTO "C##MYADMIN"."EMPLOYEE" ("ID", "NAME_TARGET", "SALARY")
VALUES (1999998, 'Alice Wonderland', (SELECT AVG("SALARY") FROM "C##MYADMIN"."EMPLOYEE"));

which contains the subquery SELECT AVG("SALARY") FROM "C##MYADMIN"."EMPLOYEE".
I tried to extract the subquery with
func (s *mockListener) EnterInsert_statement(ctx *Insert_statementContext) {
    singTblInsert := ctx.Single_table_insert()
    insertInto := singTblInsert.Insert_into_clause()
    colList := insertInto.Paren_column_list().Column_list()
    ValList := singTblInsert.Values_clause().Expressions().AllExpression()

    colNames := colList.AllColumn_name()
    for i, col := range colNames {
        colName := col.GetText()
        valStr := ValList[i].GetText()
        s.kv[colName] = valStr
    }
}

query := `INSERT INTO "C##MYADMIN"."EMPLOYEE" ("ID", "NAME_TARGET", "SALARY") VALUES (1999998, 'Alice Wonderland', (SELECT AVG("SALARY") FROM "C##MYADMIN"."EMPLOYEE"));`
lexer := NewPlSqlLexer(antlr.NewInputStream(query))
stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, 0)
p := NewPlSqlParser(stream)
tree := p.Sql_script()
l := &mockListener{
    kv: make(map[string]interface{}),
}
antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(l, tree)

and I found ValList[i].GetText() gives me SELECTAVG("SALARY")FROM"C##MYADMIN"."EMPLOYEE", which means the spaces of the subquery are all incorrectly removed.

What does your lexer do with whitespace?

You don't give the grammar but likely it has whitespace either marked as "skip" or marked "channel(HIDDEN)". tree.GetText() only gets text contained in the tree. Skipped and Hidden tokens are never in the parse tree. If Skipped, you will need to go to the "char stream" and extract the text. If Hidden, you will need to go to the "token stream" and extract the text.         String text = lexer.getInputStream().getText(tree.getSourceInterval()). (You'll need to use the appropriate Go calls instead of Java.)
